# jQuery hide div by id when other div's are visible?

Tags: jquery, html

I have four divs with the same class. Each Div has a separate ID, 1,2,3,4.
I want to use jQuery to hide my 'div id 1' if any of the other div's are visible and vice versa so if 'Div Id 4' is visible then all the other divs will be hidden.

I am brand new to jQuery so am trying to understand how I might do this. I would be grateful if somebody could please show me how I would be able to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if  ($("#tracker2").is(":visible")) {
    $("#tracker1").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stages" id="1">Supplier Contacted</div>
<div class="stages" id="2">Supplier Registered</div>
<div class="stages" id="3">Audit Complete</div>
<div class="stages" id="4">Decision Made</div>
```

Comment: what if more than one of them are visible? who has priority?

Comment: `when other div's are visible` what exactly do you mean by this? If something is not visible, then wouldn't it be hidden already? Or do they somehow started out hidden and you wish to use javascript to toggle them?

Answer (score 3):

This will hide all of your stages as it will match all elements with class `.stages`

```
$('.stages').hide();
```

This will then show just the stage with ID 2:

```
$('#stage-2').show();
```

You will need to change your IDs so they are prefixed with text as ID don't work in all contexts if they're just numbers. So your html should be:

```
<div class="stages" id="stage-1">Supplier Contacted</div>
<div class="stages" id="stage-2">Supplier Registered</div>
<div class="stages" id="stage-3">Audit Complete</div>
<div class="stages" id="stage-4">Decision Made</div>
```

You will also need to get the ID of the clicked item, which I assume you are doing already to get to this stage. You will find that once you are inside you click handler you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the thing just clicked, so:

```
$(this).show();
```

should be sufficient. In fact, this is better as you can now remove the IDs altogether from the HTML unless you need them for something else

My [fiddle here shows this](http://jsfiddle.net/u2uf8pt2/1/) - though I've also replaced show and hide with opacity setting in css so the hidden elements are actually still clickable!